# One email inbound adapter for multiple email address

Tags: spring-integration, jakarta-mail

We have more than 200 email addresses which are used to do integration with our customers, and most of the email process logic are same, we want to migrate those emails to Spring integration inbound email adapter, however we don't want to repeat copy and paste following code snippet

```
 <int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="mailAdapter"
                                        store-uri="${uri}"
                                        channel="emailInboundChannel"
                                        auto-startup="true"
                                        should-delete-messages="false"
                                        search-term-strategy="unseenSearchTermStrategy"
                                        java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
        <int-mail:transactional synchronization-factory="syncFactory" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    </int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter>
```

Is there any way that we can just use one email adapter with fixed rate poller to connect to as many email address  as we can , then send the email message to same inbound channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can move to Java & Annotations configuration, especially Java DSL, then you can get a gain of dynamic flows: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows. So, you could iterate over your emails and register IMAP channel adapters for them.

This is really hard to do with an XML configuration...

You can consider to use a spring-integration-flow extension though: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-flow, but it’s really recommended to move to Java configuration these days.

Comment: Hi, Artem
For some simple integration flows, we still use xml configuration, do  you recommend to move to Java for all?

Comment: Yes, that is where we are heading with all the Spring Boot features